# Bridging header finds file only with full path

Tags: ios, import, bridging-header

I have a project that requires a local framework.
The project has the frameworks set up in a frameworks folder.
The new local framework is placed in it as well. The result folder structure is like that:

```
project
-- frameworks
---- theFramework.framework
------Headers
--------TheFramework.h
--------file1.h
--------file2.h
--------subfolder
----------Subfolder.h
----------Another.h
```

In the Bridging header the TheFramework.h and the Subfolder.h need to be imported.

It looks like that:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import <TheFramework/TheFramework.h> //This one is working just fine
#import <subfolder/Subfolder.h> //This one fails with File not found

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

If I change `#import <subfolder/Subfolder.h>` to `#import <TheFramework/subfolder/Subfolder.h>` then it seems that the file is found because then it fails in Subfolder.h where it tries to do `#import <subfolder/Another.h>` and fails again with a Not found

If I change `subfolder/Another.h` to `TheFramework/subfolder/Another.h` then it works here as well.

Now in my real life scenario I have 4 header files in different subfolders all importing around 50 other files so changing all of the imports will be... annoying. 
Also if later we want to update to a newer version of the framework, all the changed imports will be lost.

Does someone know how I can solve that issue? Either by having the project find the imports as already defined or by for example defining a value somewhere that makes the compiler understand that `subfolder/file.h` equals to `TheFramework/subfolder/file.h` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution I had to add

```
"$(SRCROOT)/frameworks/theFramework.framework/Headers"
```

to my targets User Header Search Paths (Target -> Build Settings -> User header search paths.
This seems to let the compiler know where additionally search for header files including subfolders.